# Getting programmatical access to the PostgreSQL exception

Tags: java, postgresql, javafx

I have the following problem. I am inserting data to Postgres database through my javafx interface.

When i import some data to my database, sometimes primary key is violated and I am getting the following stack error:

```
 catch(PSQLException e){

       System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
}


 duplicate key value violates unique constraint "importedDocumentPK"
 Detail: Key (part_id, supplier_id, temp_id, qty, color, sign_id, state_id)=(41A213752P9, 750, 7049, 48, 5, 1, 1) already exists.
```

My question is. How can I save information about this row (41A213752P9, 750, 7049, 48, 5, 1, 1) in my program?

Answer (score 1):

This information is only available as a text string in the error message in current versions of PostgreSQL. However, the upcoming 9.3 release will expose this as more detailed fields, see  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQRESULTERRORFIELD for details. I would assume the JDBC driver will expose the same fields as well, though I'm not sure if they've defined the interface yet.